# Can one application access other applications data querying the key in Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

It would be an enormous security flaw if it does.

Proposed method:

```
entity = db.get(key)
```

source: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/creatinggettinganddeletingdata.html#Getting_an_Entity_Using_a_Key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. But you could do it using [remote_api](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/remote_api.html) (and with the permission of the other app's owner).

Answer (score 3):

No you cannot, unless there is a particular bug you have discovered.  Is there any particular reason you think it is possible?  This seems fairly easy to test, if you are worried about it.  Just create two apps and try to access data from app A from app B.