# Share a model through apps without API

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Is it possible to share a model through other apps? if possible, how to do this.

Yeah, maybe we can implement API for those apps, But if apps can share their models for each other without any external libs, it would be cool :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could possibly broaden your definition of "other applications" in the original question to include other *versions* of the same application (where these versions are really your "other applications").  If so, then this could be possible by deploying each of your "other applications" as a different version of the same application.  That way they should be able to share the same data store.  I've not yet attempted this myself but from what I read this should be possible.  Might get some more info if anyone posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9456971/any-issues-using-multiple-gae-app-versions-to-get-multiple-apps-to-share-the-sam), or if I end up trying this myself I'll let you know.

Update: I tried this out and it works but with one minor and one possibly significant issue.  The minor issue is that you have to work out a way to duplicate the same data model across your two apps (or at least as much as you need).  The bigger issue is that datastore commits made in one application may not be visible to the other application for quite some time, and that amount of time varies depending on where/how you're deploying.

Answer (score 1):

There is [no way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8956230/can-i-access-datastore-entities-of-my-other-google-app-engine-applications) ([yet?](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1300)) for an App to open its datastore to other Apps, if that is what you mean.

You'd have to go through an HTTP interface (which could probably be derived from the model classes directly, and thus shared). The [remote_api](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/remote_api.html) standardizes this somewhat.

Comment: I thought that db methods are based on RPC, so it would be no problem to do that :)

Comment: Yes, it is no problem, and that is how the remote_api works (tunneling the RPC calls to another app). You do want some kind of access control here, though. The enhancement ticket I linked to ("yet?") has recently been Accepted, so maybe they are working on it now.