# Deploy gcloud app to diff environments

Tags: google-app-engine, deployment, gcloud, create-react-app

I have an app that uses the following command to deploy a static app generated by create-react-app:

```
gcloud app deploy --project MY_PROJECT -v dev
```

After that, my app is available on **myproject.appstop.com**.

But I don't figure out how to deploy this app using a diff URL for each environment. Like.: dev.myproject.appspot.com, stg.myproject.com and so on.

If you know or have other ideas about how to solve this please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you understand by environment. I would definitely recommend you to create different projects for the different environments (my-project-dev, my-project-staging, my-project-test, my-project-prod...)

If you just want to have a different url for your deployment, you are doing ok by using the -v (version parameter).

Once you've deployed again:

```
gcloud app deploy --project MY_PROJECT -v test
```

you'll have both versions accessible at:

- dev.myproject.appspot.com
- test.myproject.appspot.com

Also, check [Dan's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48958338/1666903) as it contains very relevant info.

Comment: Thanks! Just notice that the version URLs don't have SSL.

Answer (score 2):

To complement @MarCialR's answer, you can use SSL as well, but with `*-dot-*` URLs like `https://test-dot-myproject.appspot.com`, see [Targeted routing](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-requests-are-routed#targeted_routing).

But personally I'm not a big fan of a version-based environment, it brings trouble, see [Continuous integration/deployment/delivery on Google App Engine, too risky?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40192557/continuous-integration-deployment-delivery-on-google-app-engine-too-risky/40193364#40193364)

I chose to implement environments at app level - each environment as a different app, each with its own URL. See [Advantages of implementing CI/CD environments at GAE project/app level vs service/module level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43218971/advantages-of-implementing-ci-cd-environments-at-gae-project-app-level-vs-servic?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Since I'm using a wildcard custom-domain SSL certificate I'm simply mapping the different apps (environments) to different hosts/subdomains in my custom domain - thus ensuring everything works as expected with a custom domain at every point in the CI/CD pipeline, no surprises in production.