# How to use custom domain name in google app engine with different versions?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, subdomain

I am using google app engine as a server for  my android and web application,I developed android app using Android Studio and Web application using Eclipse.I deployed two version in app engine 1st version points by android application and 2nd version points by Web application . I have my own domain name which points default version of app engine .My question is how to point 2nd version by custom domain name. I read google developer blog but i can't understand properly.Please help.

Comment: Can you try look at this discussion - How to use Google app engine with my own naked domain (not subdomain)? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/817809/how-to-use-google-app-engine-with-my-own-naked-domain-not-subdomain

Comment: i read this ,my custom domain works and points to default version and i want my custom domain points version 2

Comment: i want to replace this (https://2-dot-myAppID.appspot.com/) from my Custom domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really shouldn't attempt to run the android and the web "applications" as 2 versions of the same GAE application - that's not the intended use for versions. You'll run into trouble at least with routing traffic to the correct "application", with deploying updates and, as you already observed, with mapping to custom domains.

The proper way to run such separate "applications" as part of one GAE application is to make them separate [**services/modules**](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/an-overview-of-app-engine#services_the_building_blocks_of_app_engine) of that GAE app. Each service can have multiple versions. Each service (actually each service's default version) can be mapped to a custom (sub)domain as needed.

It should not be very complicated to convert your current app to a multi-service app: just copying the 2 versions of the code in 2 side-by-side subdirectories of your app directory and updating the configuration files should cover over 95% of the job.

Comment: thanx Dan Cornilescu for answer

Comment: i want to replace this (2-dot-myAppID.appspot.com) from my Custom domain

Comment: You can't - custom domains are always mapped to the default versions.

Comment: can I deploy services/modules of same project with different IDE .I want to deploy one module from Eclipse and one module from Android Studio.is it possible??

Comment: @ShailendraKushwah GAE itself has no problem with that, the answer depends on the IDE capabilities, some are not yet capable of handling multi-module apps. But you can always fallback to manual deployment from the respective app dirs using the SDK CLI utilities (most IDEs simply invoke those behind the scene anyways). Just make sure all code changes in the IDE are flushed to disk before deploying.