# How to add Google IAP (Identity Aware Proxy) resources?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-authentication, google-identity, google-iap

I am testing Google IAP on an Appengine project.
This project consit of 3 services (formerly known as modules).
Each one represent an environment (default is dev, staging and prod).

My problem is that only one resource is listed in the IAP menu:
The one corresponding to the defaulf version of the default service.

How can I consider other services/version when using Google IAP ?

Thx!

Comment: do you have multiple projects for each of the environments  ?

Comment: I have only one project. An environmnet is represented by a service (module). Am I clear ?

Comment: Maybe yet another reason for which environments should be done at the app/project level, not at the service/module one? See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40192557/continuous-integration-deployment-delivery-on-google-app-engine-too-risky and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40988295/how-to-use-custom-domain-name-in-google-app-engine-with-different-versions

Comment: Yeah, the more I read about it, the more I regret this architecture...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't set access permissions at the service level. IAP only applies at the GAE App level and or GCE backend service.

From a best practices perspective, Dan is correct. You generally want to have separate projects for each environment.