# GAE NDB Datastore new feature: Access Datastore entities from other GAE app

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Reading the new documentation of GAE NDB Datastore:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass#class_methods

> ```
> get_by_id(id, parent=None, app=None, namespace=None, **ctx_options)
> ```
>
> Returns an entity by ID. This is really just a shorthand for `Key(cls, id).get()`.
>
> Arguments
>
> `id` A string or integer key ID. parent Parent key of the model to
>   get.
>
> `app` (keyword arg) ID of app. If not specified, gets data for current
>   app.
>
> `namespace` (keyword arg) Namespace. If not specified, gets data for
>   default namespace.
>
> `**ctx_options` Context options Returns a model instance or None if not found.

I discover this new `app` parameter.  This is what I needed since a long time ago!!!!!
I just tried to access datastore of app "xxxxxdev" from app "xxxxxglobal" but i get this error:

```
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 1373, in check_rpc_success
    raise _ToDatastoreError(err)
BadRequestError: app s~xxxxxglobal cannot access app xxxxxxdev's data
```

I added the accounts services  xxxxxdev@appspot.gserviceaccount.com and xxxxxglobal@appspot.gserviceaccount.com as admin of the each other in this link:
https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam/

But I still receive the problem.

Can anyone help me? I need to know where in the control panel I can grant datastore access to other app in App Engine.

Comment: I'd love to see an answer to this.  The Google service account stuff is very confusing and I haven't found any good documentation.

Comment: Possibly related to this upcoming feature: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1300.

Comment: Something *might* be working already, as suggested in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25747058/4495081

Comment: Adding to the confusion, now App Engine's stuff is all entangled with the rest of cloud, so it's much harder to find relevant settings. My hunch is that although those two users have admin access to each other's data, there's also something app-level that has to be granted.

Comment: Nobody has any news on this question?

Comment: Any answer from the Google / NDB Team?  I can connect to ther GAE app datastore using Cloud Datastore API (see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8956230/can-i-access-datastore-entities-of-my-other-google-app-engine-applications/38997428#38997428 ) but when I try to connect using ndb and the app parameter, it appears the error again... So it's not a problem of permissions but a ndb implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, ndb doesn't use the Cloud Datastore API and in its normal mode of operation can't connect to another app's Datastore - it connects natively to the Datastore of the app the code is running on.

You can, however, use the [remote api](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/remoteapi) to have ndb connect to the Datastores of different apps from the development environment.

There is currently [an open Feature Request in the [Public Issue Tracker for App Engine](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1300) for the possibility of accessing multiple Datastores from a single app. Feel free to post a Feature Request for ndb specifically, although from [the following comments in the source](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/datastore-ndb-python/blob/master/ndb/tasklets.py#L1210) it appears this is already something that's being worked-on:

```
 current_app_id = os.environ.get('APPLICATION_ID', None)
  if current_app_id and current_app_id != app_id:
    # TODO(pcostello): We should support this so users can connect to different
    # applications.
    raise ValueError('Cannot create a Cloud Datastore context that connects '
                     'to an application (%s) that differs from the application '
                     'already connected to (%s).' % (app_id, current_app_id))
  os.environ['APPLICATION_ID'] = app_id
```