# Remote API with Google App Engine service accounts?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, remoteapi

When employing the [Remote API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/remoteapi) for Java for accessing another application's GAE datastore (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23469171/how-to-access-gae-datastore-with-objectify-and-service-account-credentials)), do I have to use an admin password (as shown in [sample code](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/remoteapi#configuring_remote_api_on_an_app_engine_client)) or can I use service account credentials instead. Calls to the Remote API should originate in an [App Engine Client](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/remoteapi#configuring_remote_api_on_an_app_engine_client), so non-password authentication seems to be the (only) sensible choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can! It's as simple as that: [RemoteApiOptions.useServiceAccountCredential](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/remoteapi/javadoc/com/google/appengine/tools/remoteapi/RemoteApiOptions.html#useServiceAccountCredential-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)

PS: You'll have to create a service account and download the key first. You have to grant the ["AppEngine Admin"-role](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12962#c14) to the service account.